# Detecting host vs target configuration

Tags: bazel

When building with `distinct_host_configuration=true`, I would like to be able to detect in a skylark rule implementation whether I am building the host or target variant.

Specifically I would like to turn off the race detection feature of the go rules if I am building a host tool, as it can be very expensive and not something you want turned on for tools you are using to perform your build steps.

Comment: What does it mean exactly that you'd turn off some feature of the go rules? Does it mean the rule would create different actions?

Comment: The rules already build all the actions, we have multiple output groups you can use to select the binary mode. What I wanted to do is change the default output to the non race version in host mode, so the tools don't run slowly with race detection just because the user asked to test a binary with race detection

Answer (score 1):

The principled solution would be to create 2 toolchains, one with race detection turned off and another with race detection turned on, and use the first for host and the second for target.

Comment: Being able to do toolchain transitions on edges would be wonderful, and solve lots of problems in a cleaner way.... let me know when I can do that :)